# How to use the Platinum uPnP SDK?

Tags: c++, qt, upnp

I would like to use the [Platinum SDK](http://www.plutinosoft.com/blog/platinum/) in order to develop a cross platform uPnP AV Host using Qt. I can't find any documentations or wiki for this library.

Does anyone already used the Platinum SDK and have some documentations for usage? Any example is of course welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at the examples in the SDK?

Comment: Yes I have seen them but it's not what I'm exactly looking for. It's difficult to add functionnalities without knowing possibilities of classes in the SDK. I hoped I would be able to generate Doxygen doc but there is no Doxygen tags in the source files.

Comment: Somebody has to write it.  It is Open Source, that somebody could be you.